# reledmac: Problem with RTL apparatus

Tags: hebrew, reledmac, right-to-left, lemma

I'm using reledmac to edit Hebrew texts. As the texts themselves are written right-to-left, I also want my apparatuses to behave that way. For the annotations (\footnoteA) this works smoothely out-of-the-box.

The apparatus containing the textual variants behaves inconsistently - it is neither completely RTL nor LTR.  Instead, the lines are ordered LTR, while the entries are displayed as desired as RTL.

Below, you can find an MWE. I use XeLaTeX.

What did I miss? How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{polyglossia,fontspec,xunicode}
    \usepackage{libertine} 
      \usepackage[12pt]{extsizes}
      \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} 
      \setmainlanguage{hebrew}
    \usepackage[series={A,B},noend,noeledsec,noledgroup]{reledmac} 
    \Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
    \arrangementX[A]{paragraph}
    
    \makeatletter
    \let\footnoteruleA=\right@footnoterule
    \let\Afootnoterule=\right@footnoterule
    \makeatother
    
    \Xwraplemma{\RL}
    \Xbeforeinserting\RTL
    \beforeinsertingX\RTL
    
      \firstlinenum{0}
      \linenumincrement{1}
    \linenummargin{outer}
    \fnpos{critical-familiar}
    
    \begin{document} 
    
     \beginnumbering 
  \pstart גם אני \edtext{מסכימה}{\lemma{מסכימה} \Afootnote{מסכים \emph{L}}} \edtext{אתך}{\lemma{אתך} \Afootnote{אתה \emph{L}}},
    
     \edtext{חביבי}{\lemma{חביבי} \Afootnote{חבר שלי \emph{L}}}
     
     
      \emph{והיתה לאו״ת ברית}\footnoteA{בראשית יז, יא}
      
       
      \emph{כאב את בן ירצה}\footnoteA{משלי ג, יב}
      \pend      \endnumbering 
       \end{document}
```

[image: Desired output:]

Comment: there is many question about this topic. Did you look for example on https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Breledmac%5D+rtl ? basically, all you need is to find the good "hook" to insert RTL switching macro. There are so many possibilities when dealing with RTL apparatus that is not easy to provide a "ready-to-use" solution.

Comment: I really have worked through many of the questions on the topic, but I can't wrap my head around the problem.

Comment: Hum, 

could please send an example of what output you expect ?

Comment: as explained, it is very difficult to deal with RTL in reledmac, as each edition have its own rule when mixing content... I asked many time to reledmac user using RTL to produce a short memento about that, get many promisses, but never any answer.

Comment: Sure, I'd be happy to help other users of reledmac who struggle with RTL-problems.

Comment: I have added an image of the way the apparatus should look to the original post.

Comment: I will look on this problem tomorrow.

Comment: please modifiy your original post, in ordre to be more explicit about this image, for people who won't look on the conversation.

Comment: sorry, but if 1) I passover the "lemma" bug when running (on which I am currently looking for), I get exactly the expected ouptut, regarding the orientation of the notes. But  just one a question : why using \lemma with exactly the same content the the first argument of edtext?

Comment: WHat I get is https://drop.infini.fr/r/342DAE6gkx#lXhaiECdKncuPPWehf3I/JOQqeGeHbAIZmuOTNRfbHs= (with some corrections for the footnote rule), It seems it look like what you expect.

Comment: This was unexpected to me. After some tinkering, I discovered that my LaTeX-distribution was to blame. With this resolved, the output is now as desired.

Comment: nice. Happy to know that